# PHP Can't compare string with filename

Tags: php

I have following filename "test.mkv" from an array
and following string "test.mkv".

PHP says it not equal if I do this:

```
$dir    = '/folder';
$filesarray = scandir($dir);    
if($filesarray[0] == $string)
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `$filesarray[0]` contains your string? `var_dump($filesarray)`

Comment: Yes it contains!

Comment: From the [scandir man](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) the output is `Array( [0] => .
    [1] => ..` So I don't think `$filesarray[0]` contains `test.mkv`, are we seeing all of the code here or are we missing some?

Comment: Try `if (in_array($string, $filesarray))` instead of testing a specific index.

Comment: If you just want to know if a file is in a directory, use `file_exists("folder/$string")`, there's no need to read the whole directory into an array first.

Answer (score 2):

```
$found = in_array($string, scandir("/folder"));
```

`$found` will be `true` if any file matches your `$string` content. Usually indices `0` and `1` contain respectively `.` and `..` so I doubt that your check can work...

If your intention is just to check if a given file exists, use this:

```
file_exists("folder/$string")
```